# Banner ad is not showing for my Ad unit ID , android

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob

i want to show banner add to my android application, it is showing banner add ,if i use google's test id

```
 <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
```

but if i add my ad unit id, it is showing nothing .  i need some help

this is my build,gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.radioplanet"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 6
    versionName "6.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1', 
   {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'

 }
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this is my id

```
 <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3490247194261556/7252350096</string>
```

this is my java code from fragment

```
 MobileAds.initialize(getActivity(), "ca-app-pub-3490247194261556/7252350096");

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) rootView .findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: what permissions you are using? Also upload logs

Comment: Can you share your layout xml?

Comment: also show your permissions.

Comment: @Jaison Joseph Check this link : https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: Try replacing `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1 with `com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.1`. Check this [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start)

Comment: my xml and permissions are proper coz basically it works with internet, and add view i copied from official documentation

Answer (score 1):

You should have to try this:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3490247194261556/7252350096" />
```

put this code in your java file:

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

Advertise.display(getApplicationContext());
if (Utility.isOnline(this)) {
    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

**Note:-** if you created your Ad-Unit id just now and trying to use it instantly then it will not works because after the creation of Ad-Unit id it will take time up to 1 or 2 hours for activation from AdMob.

Comment: I am doing this on fragment , so can u change ur code for fragment

Comment: Ya but fragment will also locate in activity so i think you should have to put it in Activity.

Comment: No its not locating

Answer (score 0):

Verify app-level build.gradle (excerpt)

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.1'
    }


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: after adding compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.1' geting error

Comment: @JaisonJoseph   Please Provide Your Error Log.

Comment: fail to resolve:compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.1'

Comment: i have to install Google Repository i guess, are you sure that if i add compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.1 , it will work ?

Comment: No, it will not work. But Firebase is latest to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

XML code

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

JAVA code

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Android Manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Inside string.xml file

<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-Your add unit id</string>

Comment: or i should add compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.1' in dependencies

Answer (score 0):

> Making ad requests requires the networking permissions INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, so these must also be declared in the manifest