# Android ads doen't show up

Tags: android, admob

I've just finished developping my application and now I'm trying to make test ads show up in my application but it doesn't work, I've already added the required code to the gradle

**Manifest**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.pc.wolrdwidefacts">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

I've copying just the first part of the manifest because it's too long.

**XML file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/alcohol1"
tools:context=".alcohol1">
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next_btn"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="218dp"
    android:background="@drawable/next" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/menu" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

**Acitivity code**

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alcohol1);

    MobileAds.initialize(this,
            "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Please try this may it will works for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43487016/6096821

Comment: Which error code you are getting from admob error response??